# [boost.asio]closing tcp::socket or tcp::acceptor in different thread from the I/O thread

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Could I close tcp::socket in different thread from the sync-reading thread?
It looks like:

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket* tcp_socket;  //blocking mode
```

thread1:

```
while(true){
   try{
       std::vector<char> read_buffer(10);
       tcp_socket->read_some( boost::asio::buffer( read_buffer ) );
  }
  catch(boost::system::system_error& e){
  //TODO
  break;
  }
}
```

thread2:

```
tcp_socket->shutdown(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both);
tcp_socket->close();
```

I saw the [document](http://think-async.com/Asio/boost_asio_1_4_8/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/socket.html#boost_asio.reference.ip__tcp.socket.thread_safety) of tcp::socket. They say the object is thread-unsafty.But the demo code seems working well.
So Is it safe? What about tcp::acceptor? Could I invoke close and accept in multithreading
on same tcp::acceptor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation states that `tcp::socket` is not thread safe for shared objects.

Don't count on it seemingly working as a guarantee that it will always work.

Moreover, closing a socket from another thread, at the socket layer, is not a portable way of getting the blocking thread to unblock.

Here's what I would suggest:

- Use the asynchronous APIs for asio.
- Protect the socket with a mutex to prevent concurrent access or use an asio strand to serialize the access to it.

Quoting the author on a [similar](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.asio.user/2018) question:

> Actually...
>
> In practice, it will probably work on the platforms asio currently 
>   supports**. However, I have deliberately specified the interface such 
>   that it is *not* thread safe. This is to permit implementations to
>   store  additional state in the socket object without needing explicit 
>   synchronisation.
>
> If you want to run multiple concurrent operations on the same socket, 
>   the safe, portable way is to use the asynchronous operations.
>
> **Unless you make the socket non-blocking.
>
> Cheers, Chris

Answer (score 2):

It is safe, as long as you can guarantee that no other thread is using the `tcp_socket` after closing. For your example, if thread1 was still in the read-loop while thread2 was attempting to close the thread, you will have a race-condition.

You can use [thread-shared variables](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref) to signal thread1 to quit the loop and use [a barrier](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.barriers) to ensure the socket is only closed after thread1 is in a safe state.

Comment: Thansk for your reply. I run my demo code.There is no lock to sync thread1 and thread2.After tcp_socket->close() is invoked,thread1 catch a "End of File" exception,and break.I found no document gving this a reasonable explanation.

Comment: Without a lock, anything can happen. You probably just got lucky on your platform, but that doesn't mean it's portable. As the other answer stressed out: *Any* kind of concurrent access (i.e. two threads accessing the same object at the same time) will lead to trouble. It is only safe to share objects between threads if you prohibit concurrent access.